# React.cloneElement clone already cloned element to add new props

Tags: reactjs

I have have `TestWrapper` component that clones `element` and is supposed to make the background blue. `Test` is also doing the same, but instead sets `color`. I was expecting the rendered element to have blue background and red text, but it is only `red`. Here is the example:

```
const Test: React.FC<{ element: React.ReactElement }> = ({ element }) => {
  return React.cloneElement(element, {
    const isSelected = useIsSelected();
    style: { ...element.props.style, color: isSelected ? 'red' : 'black' }
  });
};

const TestWrapper: React.FC<{ element: React.ReactElement }> = ({
  element
}) => {
  // BackgroundColor is blue
  const { backgroundColor } = useTheme();
  return React.cloneElement(element, {
    style: { ...element.props.style, background: backgroundColor }
  });
};

export function App() {
  return <TestWrapper element={<Test element={<h1>Heading</h1>} />} />;
}
```

How can I achieve this? I could do this differently, but I have to be able to access hook methods from `Test` and `TestWrapper`.

Simple codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-bassi-ve1ym?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `TestWrapper` you are cloning the `Test` component and applying your `style` props to it, which are not being passed down to the element that it's cloning itself. Just returning a cloned element doesn't create a referential equality where doing something to the component will affect the element it is cloning. You would need to give a `style` prop to `Test` and pass it down to the element being cloned:

```
const Test: React.FC<{
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  element: React.ReactElement;
}> = ({ element, style }) => {
  return React.cloneElement(element, {
    style: { ...element.props.style, ...style, color: "red" }
  });
};
```

I made a fork [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-dijkstra-4scxe?file=/src/App.tsx:224-449). Hopefully this helps!